# Are there any non-Arnold T-800 models?

Tags: the-terminator-series

Since the T-800 was meant to be an infiltration unit, it doesn't make much sense for there to be multiples of the same face. But somehow at least five separate terminators from the movies are all replicas of Arnold (forgiving some aging from the actor)

Are there any hints at non-Arnold T-800 models or an explanation as to why all T-800s look the same?

Comment: Fair enough. That indirectly answers my question.

Comment: There's an explanation [here](http://www.jamescamerononline.com/T2FAQ.htm).  It includes concept art for scenes that weren't used, where future John finds the storage facility housing inactive Terminators.  One rack has Terminators that look like Arnold, each of the other racks has Terminators that have a different appearance.